# Extract values from object in django

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to extract the '35' and '34' values from this object:

```
[<FriendshipRequest: 35>, <FriendshipRequest: 34>]
```

These are primary keys which i would like to use as parameters to get information about the specific user the primary key relates to but I am unsure on how to separate the values from the rest of the object attributes to substitute into `User.objects.get(pk=pk)` as at the moment `pk=<FriendshipRequest: 35>` whereas i'd like `pk=35`.

I am just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Cheers

Comment: Why are you comparing `User.pk` with `FriendShipRequest.pk`?

Answer (score 0):

What's the name of the user field on the FriendshipRequest model?
So the problem is that pk is the primary key of FriendshipRequest in this example and you need the foreign key of the user... 
So for example if you are looking for the user who is the sender(Under the assumption that this fields name is **sender** inside the FriendshipRequest model), you would access it by friendship_request.sender or if you just want the primary key of the user friendship_request.sender.pk

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't just use `User.objects.get(pk=FriendshipRequestObj.id)`.  
 I am assuming `id` as your `pk` in model.